# one to one bidirectional hibernate mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I was trying to implement hibernate one-to-one bidirectional mapping between Person class and Address class using annotation. While running the program it gave me some errors

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient      
instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.vaannila.domain.Person
    at org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:397)
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.isDirty(ManyToOneType.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory.findDirty(TypeFactory.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.findDirty(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3123)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.dirtyCheck(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:479)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.isUpdateNecessary(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:26)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
    at com.vaannila.domain.Add.main(Add.java:58)
```

following are my classes

Person.java

```
package com.vaannila.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;


@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person implements Serializable {

private long personId;
private String personName;
private Address personAddress;
    private Set<Phone> personPhoneNumbers = new HashSet<Phone>(0);

public Person() {
}

public Person(String personName, Address personAddress, Set<Phone> personPhoneNumbers) {
    this.personName = personName;
    this.personAddress = personAddress;
            this.personPhoneNumbers = personPhoneNumbers;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "PERSON_ID")
public long getPersonId() {
    return this.personId;
}

public void setPersonId(long personId) {
    this.personId = personId;
}

@Column(name = "PERSON_NAME", nullable = false, length = 100)
public String getPersonName() {
    return this.personName;
}

public void setPersonName(String personName) {
    this.personName = personName;
}

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Address getPersonAddress() {
    return this.personAddress;
}

public void setPersonAddress(Address personAddress) {
    this.personAddress = personAddress;
}

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "PERSON_PHONE", joinColumns =
    { @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns =
    { @JoinColumn(name = "PHONE_ID") })
    public Set<Phone> getPersonPhoneNumbers() {
        return personPhoneNumbers;
    }

    public void setPersonPhoneNumbers(Set<Phone> personPhoneNumbers) {
        this.personPhoneNumbers = personPhoneNumbers;
    }

}
```

Addres.java

```
package com.vaannila.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
public class Address implements Serializable {

private long addressId;
private String street;
private String city;
private String state;
private String zipcode;
    private Person person;


public Address() {
}


@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "ADDRESS_ID")
public long getAddressId() {
    return this.addressId;
}

public void setAddressId(long addressId) {
    this.addressId = addressId;
}

@Column(name = "ADDRESS_STREET", nullable = false, length=250)
public String getStreet() {
    return this.street;
}

public void setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
}

@Column(name = "ADDRESS_CITY", nullable = false, length=50)
public String getCity() {
    return this.city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

@Column(name = "ADDRESS_STATE", nullable = false, length=50)
public String getState() {
    return this.state;
}

public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}

@Column(name = "ADDRESS_ZIPCODE", nullable = false, length=10)
public String getZipcode() {
    return this.zipcode;
}

public void setZipcode(String zipcode) {
    this.zipcode = zipcode;
}

    @OneToOne
    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

}
```

Phone.java

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package com.vaannila.domain;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
*
* @author junaid
*/
@Entity
@Table(name = "PHONE")
public class Phone implements java.io.Serializable {

private long phoneId;
private String phoneType;
private String phoneNumber;

public Phone() {
}

public Phone(String phoneType, String phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneType = phoneType;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "PHONE_ID")
public long getPhoneId() {
    return this.phoneId;
}

public void setPhoneId(long phoneId) {
    this.phoneId = phoneId;
}

@Column(name = "PHONE_TYPE", nullable = false, length=10)
public String getPhoneType() {
    return this.phoneType;
}

public void setPhoneType(String phoneType) {
    this.phoneType = phoneType;
}

@Column(name = "PHONE_NUMBER", nullable = false, length=15)
public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return this.phoneNumber;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

}
```

Main class

```
  package com.vaannila.domain;

 import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
 import org.hibernate.Session;
 import org.hibernate.Transaction;

 import com.vaannila.util.HibernateUtil;
 import java.util.HashSet;
 import java.util.Set;

 public class Add {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;
    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();

                    //Transaction for person 1 start
                    Address address1 = new Address();
                    address1.setCity("Bangalore");
                    address1.setState("Karnataka");
                    address1.setStreet("Ring Road");
                    address1.setZipcode("560000");

                    Set<Phone> phoneNumbers = new HashSet<Phone>();
                    phoneNumbers.add(new Phone("house","32354353"));
                    phoneNumbers.add(new Phone("mobile","9889343423"));

                    Person person = new Person();
                    person.setPersonName("Junaid");
                    person.setPersonAddress(address1);
                    person.setPersonPhoneNumbers(phoneNumbers);

                    session.save(person);
                     //Transaction for person 1 end

                     //Transaction for person 2 start
                    Set<Phone> phoneNumbers2 = new HashSet<Phone>();
                    phoneNumbers2.add(new Phone("house","32354353"));
                    phoneNumbers2.add(new Phone("mobile","9889343423"));

                    Person person1 = new Person();
                    person1.setPersonName("Wayne");
                    person1.setPersonPhoneNumbers(phoneNumbers2);


                    Address address2 = new Address();
                    address2.setCity("Chennai");
                    address2.setState("Tamil Nadu");
                    address2.setStreet("OMR Road");
                    address2.setZipcode("4000");
                    address2.setPerson(person1);

        session.save(address2);
                     //Transaction for person 2 end

        transaction.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }

}

 }
```

All tables are getting created, but when deleting the table, all except Person and Address is not getting deleted.

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working guys.

i missed out mappedBy property. After adding that its working fine.

```
@OneToOne(mapperdBy="personAddress")
public Person getPerson() {
    return person;
}
```