# Hibernate makes insert twice and results in unique key constraint violation

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jboss

hi I'm getting this "javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint"

I have two tables A and B,

A has id, b_id, B has id,A_id's.
A - oneToMany , B - manyToOne relationship.

on A,

```
@OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinColumn(name = "LATEST_VERSION_ID") @Valid
@EntityProperty(type = "GuidKey", relation = "B.id")
```

on B,

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name = "A_ID") @Valid
@EntityProperty(type = "Key", relation = "A.id")
```

when I create Page A I was able to Do so, But when I try to update I get unique constraint violation on table 'B'.

It says the record already exist.

Comment: Why is A set to @OneToOne instead of @OneToMany?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a bi-directional relation using the `mappedBy` property.

See:

- [one to one bidirectional hibernate mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777333/one-to-one-bidirectional-hibernate-mapping)
- http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example-annotation
- http://www.codereye.com/2009/04/hibernate-bi-directional-one-to-one.html

Also, @EntityProperty isn't required for this.  The foreign key should be in one table in one-to-one.